# New column which indicate min date from group of value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add new column which will be indicating min value of subgroup.

```
Id          ShopId      OrderDate
12232018    12229018    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
12232018    12229018    2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
12232018    12394018    2012-02-02 00:00:00.000
12232018    11386005    2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
12232018    14347023    2012-04-02 00:00:00.000
12232018    14026026    2014-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

Here is the result I want to get:

```
NewCol    Id        ShopId      OrderDate
1         12232018  12229018    2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
1         12232018  12229018    2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
0         12232018  12394018    2012-02-02 00:00:00.000
0         12232018  11386005    2012-03-01 00:00:00.000
0         12232018  14347023    2012-04-02 00:00:00.000
0         12232018  14026026    2014-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

Because ShopId have min OrderDate for Id I would like to assign '1' to this ShopId.

Comment: 2nd row OrderDate value correct?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: Yes, i have tried but only using rank function but it is not what i expected

Comment: Feel free to include the query you tried in your question. We can then see what went wrong and point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, ShopId, OrderDate,
       CASE 
          WHEN MIN(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, ShopId) = 
               MIN(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS NewCol
FROM mytable
```

The query uses windowed version of `MAX` in order to compare the minimum-per-`Id` `OrderDate` to the minimum-per- (`Id`, `ShopId`) date. If these two values are the same, then we mark the corresponding (`Id`, `ShopId`) partition with 1.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/YFANO53306)

Answer (score 1):

You can use min with windowing function to get this as below:

```
select NewCol = Case when orderdate = min(orderdate) over() then 1 else 0 end,*
    from yourtable
```

--Probably you might require to add Partition by Id or shopId depends on requirement

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant than the others, but is ANSI

```
select MyTable.*, case when a1.mindate = orderdate then 1 else 0 end as NewCol
from MyTable
inner join
(
select id, min(orderdate) as mindate
from Mytable
group by id
) a1
on a1.id = MyTable.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min` with orderdate on ShopId and use that in the Case When statement like this:-

```
Select case when (a.OrderDate=b.min_order_dt) then 1 else 0 end as NewCol, a.*
from
your_table_name a
inner join
(
SELECT ShopId, min(OrderDate) as min_order_dt
from
your_table_name
group by shop_id
) b
on a.ShopId=b.ShopId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select case when t2.ShopId is null then 0 else 1 end  as newcol,t1.id,
t1.ShopiId,t1.OrderDate 
from table as t1 left join
(
select ShopId,min(OrderDate) as OrderDate from table
group by ShopId
) as t2 on t1.ShopId=t2.ShopId and t1.OrderDate=t2.OrderDate
```